# ftp_delete - file exists but not found

Tags: php, ftp

I have weird problem... as you can see.. o.O

```
$connection = ftp_connect(FTP_SERVER);
$login = ftp_login($connection, FTP_USERNAME, FTP_PASSWORD);
if ($login) {
    $file = "" . DOCUMENT_ROOT . "/uploaded_files/" . Session::GetSession('username') . "/" . $result['ftp_file_name'] . "";
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        echo "file_exists";
        if (ftp_delete($connection, $file)) {
            echo "deleted";
        } else {
            echo "file_not_found";
        }
    } else {
        echo "does_not_exists";
    }
} else {
    echo "not_logged_in";
}
```

This is the result:

> file_exists
>  **Warning**:  ftp_delete(): File not found in
>   **C:\programy\xampp\htdocs\ajax-handler.php** on line **235** file_not_found

Can anyone tell me why is this happening? It does not make any sense..

Comment: print `$file`, and check if it really exists.

Comment: Also make sure that $file is a path..

Comment: `file_exists` checks for the existence of *local* files. `ftp_delete` deletes a file on the *remote FTP server*. There's no reason that checking for the existence of a local file will guarantee that it's present on the remote server (even if it's the same server; the FTP root is probably different from PHP's root.)

Comment: Fixed it.. changed directory to where the file is located , width ftp_chdir, and sucesfully deleted it.

Comment: @brata You've checked it through an FTP client, using the same path? What happens if you try to delete it using the FTP client, with that path and the same credentials as your PHP? That should tell you what's wrong.

Comment: The path to file is ... C:/programy/xampp/htdocs/uploaded_files/random_name/353.png . I used the same path for both file_exists and ftp_file delete. Anyway I fixed it by ... ftp_chdir($connection, "/uploaded_files/random_name/) and deleted it with ftp_delete("353.png");

Comment: I would close this question and marked as anwered..  If I  knew how

Answer (score 0):

Remove DOCUMENT_ROOT and add an 'at'(@) sign before `ftp_delete`
try as follows

```
 $fileTmp =  "/uploaded_files/" . Session::GetSession('username') . "/" .                $result['ftp_file_name'] .$get_file "";

    if (@ftp_delete($connection, $fileTmp)){
```

Comment: Hiding the warning isn't a solution!

Comment: brata's code is only warning problem because there is if and else statements . It will generate warning..

Comment: @ArshidKV and what if it fails because a real problem next time? who will know about it?

Answer (score -1):

```
$connection = ftp_connect(FTP_SERVER);
            $login = ftp_login($connection, FTP_USERNAME, FTP_PASSWORD);
            if ($login) {
                $get_file=$_GET['uploaded_files'];
                $file = "" . DOCUMENT_ROOT . "/uploaded_files/" . Session::GetSession('username') . "/" . $result['ftp_file_name'] .$get_file "";
                if (file_exists($file)) {
                    echo "file_exists";
                    if (ftp_delete($connection, $file)) {
        echo "deleted";
                    } else {
                        echo "file_not_found";
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "does_not_exists";
                }
            }
        } else {
            echo "not_logged_in";
        }
ftp_close($connection);
```